# How to monitor the daily incoming Datafiles in Azure Files and save them in SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-files

I would like to log all files that are loaded into Azure storage on daily base.
Is it possible to access this information as a summary?

I need Information such as file name and upload time.
And how can I read them out and save them in the database, is there any provided service ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which way would like to get the summary?

Comment: A table format,two columns with file name and upload date as header. Or json format as long its somehow readable and processable into database probably with a storage proc. Maybe it's readable with azure data factory ?

Comment: Data Factory get Metadata can get the output you want.

Comment: solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Walerius, you're welcome! Can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Factory Get Metadata active, it can get the output you want.

Please ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

Comment: The Get Metadata works fine for the file names. I have a Folder and i am getting the childItems (the actual files and data i need). Is there any way to get the actual time/date when the data was uploaded on Azure storage ?

Comment: @Walerius In usually, the file has the meta data: `LAST MODIFIED`, if we didn't modify or change the files, that's the time when the files was uploaded. Just for now, we can't get the actual time/date when the data was uploaded.